# Trouble validating <select> using parsley.js which is being populated by an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js, parsley.js

I am having trouble validating a `<select>` element on my form. Using **knockout.js** the location is selected which then populates the Service Point based on the Location selected. Once the submit button is pressed the form is validated with **parsley.js**

I keep getting "This value is required." on the Location `<select>` when parsley tries to validate the form. It populates fine, and the values appear and flow though back to the database as expected when the validation is turned off but when the validation is turned on parsley throws the error saying "This value is required." where there is clearly a value in the Locations dropdown otherwise the Service Point would not be able to be selected.

I'm quite new to these libraries but my guess is something to do with it being populated by an object, though I didn't think that would be an issue as there is still a value there.

Hopefully I have provided enough information, if you need anything else I can provide it.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

**viewModelLocationAndServicePoint.data()**

```
[
    {
        "ServicePoints": [
            {
                "ServicePoint": "ServicePoint1"
            }
        ],
        "Location": "Location1"
    },
    {
        "ServicePoints": [
            {
                "ServicePoint": "ServicePoint1"
            },
            {
                "ServicePoint": "ServicePoint2"
            },
            {
                "ServicePoint": "ServicePoint3"
            }
        ],
        "Location": "Location2"
    }
]
```

**Population of Observables**

```
self.Location = ko.observable(data.Location().Location());
self.ServicePoint = ko.observable(data.ServicePoint());
```

**viewModelTrackFiles Output**

```
{
    "trackfile": {
        "Location": {
            "ServicePoints": [
                {
                    "ServicePoint": "ServicePoint1"
                }
            ],
            "Location": "Location1"
        },
        "TransactionMode": "",
        "ServicePoint": "ServicePoint1",
        "Status": "",
        "Comments": "",
        "Barcode": "",
        "BarcodeImageBase64": ""
    },
    "files": [],
    "printneeded": "no",
    "TransactionMode": "",
    "dispatchmode": false,
    "StaffName": "",
    "TransactionDate": "2017-02-06T16:29:49.914Z"
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="cLocation" 
    data-parsley-required="true" 
    data-bind="options: viewModelLocationAndServicePoint.data(), 
        optionsCaption:'Choose Location', 
        optionsText: 'Location', 
        value: trackfile.Location">
</select>

<div data-field-span="1" data-bind="with: trackfile.Location">
    <select id="cServicePoint" 
        data-parsley-required="true" 
        data-bind="options: ServicePoints, 
            optionsCaption:'Service Points', 
            optionsText: 'ServicePoint', 
            optionsValue: 'ServicePoint', 
            value: $parent.trackfile.ServicePoint">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use parsley? There is a validation plugin for knockout which would male more sense I think: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation . Unless you are using the knockout parsley plugin? https://github.com/gdandar/Knockout-Parsley

Comment: Thanks, to be honest I am working with what was already in place, so I don't know why :) I'm pretty sure it's just parsley and not knockout-parsley. I will look into these as I might be able to change what's being used, however it would require a big update as it's used throughout. In the mean time ideally I need a quick solution to fix this if at all possible.

Comment: I see. is it normal that the `value` points to the parent? Are you sure this returns a non-null value? (`value: $parent.trackfile.ServicePoint"`)

Comment: I used the shopping cart example http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html to help build this part and that's what they use.

Comment: I am not sure this applies to your case. Since you have this `data-bind="with: trackfile.Location"` in the div I think you just need `value: ServicePoint"` in the select

Comment: I get the following errors when I use `value: ServicePoint`: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return ServicePoint }"
Message: ServicePoint is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: ServicePoint is not defined`

Comment: Though the Service Point is not where the issue lies as it validates with no problems, the problem is with the Location.

Comment: Right! I think the options binding is expecting an array (here `options: viewModelLocationAndServicePoint.data()`). Where is your array of locations? I don't see it in the viewmodel

Comment: The array of Locations is part of the `viewModelLocationAndServicePoint.data()` the Location is in there. There are a number of nested viewmodels in one master viewmodel. Locations populates fine, and the values appear and flow though back to the database as expected when the validation is turned off but when the validation is turned on parsley throws the error saying `"This value is required."` where there is clearly a value in the Locations dropdown otherwise the Service Point would not be able to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a dirty workaround which works for now, if someone else can come up with something better or explain why Parsley is not recognising that there is actually a value in the `<select>` that would be fantastic!

I have created a hidden text `<input>` that is being populated by the `<select>` when it changes.

Then put the validation on that text `<input>`. This makes the Parsley error message appear under the `<select>` but doesn't change the background colour of the `<select>` (see screenshot below), which I can live with for now.

**HTML**

```
<select id="cLocation" 
    data-bind="options: viewModelLocationAndServicePoint.data(), 
        optionsCaption:'Choose Location', 
        optionsText: 'Location', 
        value: trackfile.Location">
</select>
<input style="display: none" type="text" id="loc" data-parsley-required="true">
```

**jQuery Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#cLocation").on("change", function () {
            //Update hidden text input to fix issue
            //where ParsleyJS is not validating Location
            //dropdown possibly due to how it is being populated
            $("#loc").val($("#cLocation option:selected").text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]